# Input with type="hidden". The server tag is not well formed

Tags: asp.net, repeater, server-side, hidden-field

What is wrong with this control?

```
<input value="<%# Eval("WebpartID")%>" type="hidden" 
 runat="server" id="hiddenserverfield" />
```

I use this hidden input field inside Reapeter. I want to bind it and later use it server side.  I get this parser error:

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

I have another hidden input, exactly the same only without `runat="server"`, and it doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quotes around bound property must be single, not double.

```
<input value='<%# Eval("WebpartID")%>' type="hidden" 
 runat="server" id="hiddenserverfield" />
```

If control is not server-side, this doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenserverfield" runat="server" 
                 Value='<%# Eval("WebpartID") %>' />
```